# Lua Nested Require Path

Tags: lua, nlua

I'm writing a tool to parse lua plugins created by other users. The only guarentee about the plugin is that it has a data.lua file in a known directory. Inside there users are free to do anything they wish. This particular plugin using require to load a file and that file loads another file. Both are relative paths but the second is relative to the location of the first file.

- data.lua
- foo/bar.lua
- foo/baz.lua

data.lua:

```
require("foo.bar")
```

foo/bar.lua:

```
require("baz")
```

When I try to execute data.lua I get an error when foo/bar.lua tries to require "baz". None of the paths it tries are ./foo/.

Any idea how I can fix this? I could find any documentation specifically about this case, it seemed like I need to hard code /foo/ into the path but I don't know it ahead of time. This seems like something that should be automatic is there a setting I'm missing or am I running the wrong version of lua? I'm using NLua 4.0

Thanks

Comment: I tested this script using node-lua and it fixes the issue for me! https://gist.github.com/hoelzro/1299679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this script using node-lua and it fixes the issue for me!

https://gist.github.com/hoelzro/1299679

Relavent code:

```
local oldrequire = require

function require(modname)
  local regular_loader = package.loaders[2]
  local loader = function(inner)
    if string.match(modname, '(.*)%.') then
      return regular_loader(string.match(modname, '(.*)%.') .. '.' .. inner)
    end
  end

  table.insert(package.loaders, 1, loader)
  local retval = oldrequire(modname)
  table.remove(package.loaders, 1)

  return retval
end
```

To get this to work with Lua 5.2 change all uses of package.loaders to package.searchers.

Also if you want to override the global require function you need this snippet as well:

```
_G.require = require
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the search behavior of require by changing the `package.path` variable.

Resources on `package.path`:

> https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path
>
> http://lua-users.org/wiki/PackagePath

Example adding foo folder to search locations:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';./foo/?.lua'
```

the `?` character will be where the string passed to require is placed.

---

Alternatively you can add a default file to load, to the `package.path`:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';./nested_require.lua'
```

Then define the behavior you would like within this file. You can use the global variable `_REQUIREDNAME` to reference the value passed to the require function.

The documentation for this method can be found here at the bottom of the page: https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

Comment: I appreciate the help but the basic behaviour isn't sufficient as I need to dynamically change the path based on the file that contains the require statement. I added an answer when I found a gist with what I needed but the moderators deleted it. I just added it back with more detail.

Comment: I have edit my answer to reflect your comments. However redefining require is not something that should be done. Even in extreme cases simply changing the package.path to a specific default file would be a better option.